# Why are the parts more expensive than a Pro Micro?

Tags: arduino, hobbyist

I have just started studying electronics and I am having a good time. In the past my experience would have been to use cheap boards, such as the Pro Micro.

What I find confusing is that parts, such as an oscillator, is often more expensive than a cheap $3 Micro Pro, which could have done the same thing with a few lines of code!

What are the benefits of using electronics parts, when a cheaper development board could do the same thing?

Comment: Your microcontroller has an oscillator in it.

Comment: @user1850479 Yes I know, but sometimes individual parts seem much more expensive than a $3 board.

Comment: If the $3 dev board had a good enough oscillator in it for the application, then probably you don't need such an expensive oscillator. You could use the much cheaper one in the dev board.

Comment: _"What I find confusing is that parts, such as an oscillator, is often more expensive than a cheap $3 Micro Pro, which could have done the same thing with a few lines of code!"_ - not without an equivalent oscillator it couldn't. Pro Micro on [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640): - $17.95. TXCO oscillator 0.5ppm :- $1.95.

Comment: @bruce yeah they created the pro micro, using real parts. Clones are much cheaper.

Comment: If you're talking about a "$3 pro micro", you're really talking about a cheap Chinese clone from Ebay (AliExpress, DealExtreme, ...). You'll find cheap oscillators there too. You'll also find that products from those sources have no datasheets, no guarantees, may or may not work, and may or may not live up to their claimed ratings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start at mouser or digikey or equivalent and look at the multiples of thousands of part prices. so something might be $1.00 in single quantity but it might be $0.20 in quantity of 10,000 and also understand IF and when you buy in those quantities you can do better than the mouser/etc price going through a distributor.  They make a profit, early raspberry pi's perhaps not, but in general there is a profit, in quantity, with quantity prices, on an automated production line, (and other cost reductions like quality), the whole board with profit can cost less than the most expensive single part on the board.

If your goal is to make a robot on your garage then just buying already made boards is often the way to go.  If you are instead evaluating a part for some mass produced product you want to make, or if you want to learn more about the part like how to field upgrade it or you want a similar part from that vendor that does not have a hobby/eval board then you would either sample a part for free or buy a few at full price, make a pcb at full price, etc.

So you may end up paying $10-$20 for something that only has a few components and is less complicated than the $3 board (and you solder yourself), but it is specific to what you want rather than something generic.  Then if you go into production then you shop around, you decide if you are buying the parts or having the contract manufacturer buy the parts (they buy in very high quantities and get the best pricing, but they add profit when they essentially sell you the parts), how to test it, etc, the whole process.

Another way to look at this.  For whatever parts are available start shopping for car parts, doors, hood, quarter, panel, battery, wheels, driveshaft, transmission, engine, etc.  Same deal you cant build that car for remotely the price that you can just buy an assembled one.

Economy of scale.

Comment: Nice work, especially for pointing out economies of scale.

Answer (score 3):

Manufacturers don't pay $3 for an oscillator. a hundred of these is under $25 https://lcsc.com/product-detail/SMD-Oscillators-XO_HD-830260003W1_C655083.html and that's still retail pricing.

Comment: I guess the ones sold on specialist sites, especially when bought in bulk, are cheaper than those sold on eBay.

Comment: eBay can be one of the most expensive places to buy individual electronics parts.  In small volumes, authorized distributors like Digikey, Mouser, Newark are usually much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

A Pro Micro, or at least the knockoff/clones you can get for 3 dollars, are not using high quality parts with warranties for lifetime. Pretty much everything on the boards are cheap parts and things like the microcontroller often straight counterfeit. Plus you are not paying for local reseller profit margins or regulatory compliance costs.

You pay for a 3 dollar board from china is not comparable to a genuine US manufactured product and name.